# How to schedule Jenkins job when files Check-in with delay

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, serena

Currently I'm using Serena DIMENSIONS as configuration management with Jenkins for continuous Integration.

Once Developer check in new files in Project folder in Serena, The Jenkins job(which detect changes in Serena DIMENSIONS,download changed files and build the software) needs to be trigger with 15 minutes Delay(Delay is require to complete check in all necessary files.

Can you please tell me the solution?

Comment: You need to provide more details, e. g. how are changes detected by the Jenkins job? What kind of job is it, e. g. freestyle or pipeline? Also, here on SO you are expected to present the results of your own research first, which will make it much more likely that people are willing to help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

With [Jenkins Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) you can create a stage that uses [`sleep`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#sleep-sleep) step. For example:

```java
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Wait') {
            agent { label 'wait-node' }
            steps {
                sleep time: 15, unit: "MINUTES"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There's one drawback - your executor is blocked for all the wait time. To work around this in elegant way you can define a dedicated node (`wait-node`) with large enough number of executors to handle waiting stages (note - other stages may run on different nodes). This way actual executors aren't blocked and you can see all waiting jobs on Jenkins Dashboard.